# Why are primary keys supposed to be clustered indexes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design, relational-database

I understand that the one and only one clustered index is on a table defines how the rows are physically ordered, e.g. in the table

```
==================================
            Contacts
==================================
 ID (P.K.) | FirstName | LastName
==================================
    1      | 'Donald'  | 'Trump'
----------------------------------
    2      | 'Crooked' | 'Hillary'
----------------------------------
    3      | 'Crazy'   | 'Bernie'
```

would mean that the 3 records are stored physically in the order shown above. But I don't understand why this helpful. Maybe in the case of an auto-incremented primary key with no gaps, like the above example, this helps for queries like

```
SELECT FirstName+LastName FROM Contacts WHERE ID=2
```

since the physical ordering enables the lookup if `ID=2` to happen in `O(1)` time (like getting an element of an array by index). But if the table is like

```
==================================
            Contacts
==================================
 ID (P.K.) | FirstName | LastName
==================================
    1      | 'Donald'  | 'Trump'
----------------------------------
    89     | 'Crooked' | 'Hillary'
----------------------------------
    12309  | 'Crazy'   | 'Bernie'
```

then the physical ordering ***disallows*** `O(1)` lookup; the best we can do is `O(log(n))`.

So why do we want primary keys to define the physical ordering of rows?

Comment: You don't always want the clustered index to be the primary key. It is not a requirement, only the default as almost always it makes the most logical sense to have the primary key also be the clustered index.

Comment: I'm not sure that a clustered index lookup is `O(1)` per se in your first example or in general.  Clustered index just means that once the item is found in the index, the actual item is there.  In a non-clustered index, even once finding the item, we still have to do a lookup in the clustered index to find the actual record (forgive me if my terminology be slightly off).

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted or marked as unclear. It is a valid question and it is quite clear to me what the OP is asking. The answer is pretty lengthy for sure as it requires a lot of information about indexes but the question itself seems pretty reasonable to me. Perhaps it has been asked before but not worth of a downvote imho.

Comment: You are describing hash indices, which are only allowed in SQL Server for memory-optimised tables. Normal, disk-based indices can only be either a B-tree or a columnstore (a heap isn't an index at all). B-tree has `O(log(n))`, columnstore is probably even worse. But even hash index will not, as I understand, guarantee `O(1)`, though it might give it sometimes.

Comment: @SeanLange This is too broad. An answer would be a tutorial on the subject.  user7127000  should read some. There isn't even anything special about the example. Additionally unfortunately the question contradicts some basics (see comments) including that its premise is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The significance of a clustered index in SQL Server is not "physical ordering" but the fact that row data is available in the leaf pages of the B-tree thus avoiding an additional lookup. The subtree cost is the same as for a nonclustered B-tree index: O(log n).

Physical ordering is really an abstraction of what actually happens inside a clustered index. Pages within [extents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/pages-and-extents-architecture-guide) are stored in *allocation order*, not necessarily ordered by clustered index key. The index key ordering is maintained in the index allocation map and in the pointer chain whereby each page points to the next (not necessarily adjacent) page. Within pages, rows are also written and stored in allocation order, not key order, and the order will not change unless the page splits. Pages themselves get resorted when indexes are rebuilt but the order is not automatically maintained between rebuilds.

Primary keys aren't necessarily the best choice for a clustered index. Those two concepts are orthogonal to each other.